# Linq2sql for Aggregate-Funktion in Where-Clause or join

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, aggregate-functions

What would be the corresponding linq2sql-Statement for the following SQL-Statement?

```
SELECT id, userName
FROM users
WHERE
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logins WHERE logins.userId=users.id) > 0
```

or written as a join:

```
SELECT id, userName
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN logins ON logins.id=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM logins WHERE userId=users.id)
WHERE logins.id IS NOT NULL
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are "user" and "login" DBSet in your context and the name of your context is "context":

```
var result = from user in context.users
             where (from  login in context.logins
                     where login.userId = user.userId
                     select login).Count() > 0
             select user.Id,userName
```